# How to determine what is occupying hard disk space?

Tags: partition, disk-usage, ssd

I have a primary SSD with all my stuff and a 2nd hard drive where I install my games. The SSD has a 120 GB capacity. Until recently, only ~20GB has been used, but something has happened and now 87GB is being used.

How do I determine what's occupying the space?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G   17M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  9.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /
tmpfs           3.9G  3.9M  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /.snapshots
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /home
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /root
/dev/sda1       112G   81G   30G  73% /var
tmpfs           792M  188K  791M   1% /run/user/1000
```

bottom of: du -m /  | sort -n | tail -88:

```
5292    /home/marko/.local/share/Steam
5652    /var
7099    /home/marko/.local
7099    /home/marko/.local/share
14065   /home
14065   /home/marko
192422  /.snapshots
216810  /
```

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered before. I'll try to find you a reference.  Upshot is that `df` shows how is used on the filesystem according to the filesystem itself. `du` works through the directory tree looking for files.  There's a bunch of reasons files may not be visible from corruption through to simply having an open file that's already been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

So I take it that the `/dev/sda1` is your 'primary' drive.

I wonder why you have it mounted so many times (five, by my count)? In terms of finding out what's taking up the space, simply run `ls -lhR` for a list of all the files and the size of each file, including subdirectories.

You can put it all in a `txt` file by running the command with a `> text.txt` after it.

Comment: I list a lot of stuff with ls -lhR but I dont get how to make it in to text.txt

Answer (score 0):

On the command-line, enter

```
ls -lhR > test.txt
```

That will print the output of the command to the file `test.txt`.

You can then open that file and read through it at your leisure.